# Android: How can I stop supporting tablets without raising my SDK version?

Tags: java, android, sdk, google-play

I have made an app but not designed a UI compatible with tablets and until I do, I would like to take it off the market for tablets. The problem is however that to use:

```
    <supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

I need to bump up the SDK version so that using xlargeScreens doesn't cause an error. This would limit the number of devices at the required minSdkVersion, something that I do not want to cut off.

It seems like a problem that shouldn't really be happening, could anyone help me out?

Comment: I might be missing something but, why not just set the maxSdkVersion to 10? That should limit it to devices with Android 2.3 and lower.

Comment: god dammit, always the easiest solution that you never think of

Comment: Actually there are few tablets using 2.2 and 2.3.Nook Color comes to mind. I can't see the problem of bumping the targetSdkVersion. Could you explain it?

Comment: You should probably just leave it there for tablets, honestly. They'll know that it isn't designed for their device, yet if they want to still use it, they can.

Answer (score 1):

According to the SDK docs, `maxSdkVersion` is not longer enforced by Android after 2.01. However, the Google Android Market will filter the app for download based on it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max

Answer (score 0):

When you submit to Amazon AppStore you can select the form factor of phone only.  Sorry, don't know the answer for Google Android Market.